# SQL get a specified column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

there are 2 tables

-OrderDetails-

```
OrderDetailID        OrderID        ProductID           Quantity
------------------------------------------------------------------
       1              10248           11          12
       2              10248           42          10
```

-Products-

```
ProductID      ProductName       Price
-----------------------------------------
    11              Queso           20
    42             Fried Mee        14
```

What i really wanna do is to extract Price from 'Product' Table and place it in 'OrderDetail' Table and match it with corresponding 'ProductID'. I felt like i have to first create a new column using 'alter table', so i did. but after that, i tried my best but i couldn't figure that out.

this means...

-OrderDetails-

```
OrderDetailID        OrderID        ProductID    Quantity  Price
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1              10248           11          12       20
       2              10248           42          10       14
```

this is what i want!

Comment: Is this a homework question? See how to ask homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? You can always write a query where you join the two tables to combine order detail with the product price. But the order detail should better have a price on its own, namely the price for which the product was bought at that time. And if that is always the current product price without exception then you might even better decide for a third table containing the products' price history instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vOrderDetailsPrice
AS 
SELECT 
a.OrderDetailID,        
a.OrderID,        
a.ProductID,           
a.Quantity,
b.Price
FROM OrderDetails a 
INNER JOIN Products b
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table using this statement:

```
SELECT 
OrderDetails.OderDetailID,
OrderDetails.OderID,
OrderDetails.ProductID,
OrderDetails.Quantity,
Product.Price
INTO
NewTable
FROM
OrderDetails, Product
WHERE
OrderDetails.ProductID = Product.ProductID;
```

Make sure that NewTable looks the way you want it to and then delete OrderDetails table. Then you can rename NewTable as OrderDetails table.

Answer (score -1):

you could use inner join to get your result

```
SELECT OD.OrderDetailID,OD.OrderID,OD.ProductID,OD.Quantity,PD.Price
FROM ORDERDETAILS OD INNER JOIN PRODUCTS PD ON OD.PRODUCTID=PD.PRODUCTID
```